# Use Fermat's little theorem to find remainder of powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to use Fermat's little theorem to find the value of$$
x \uparrow \uparrow k \mod m =  \underbrace{x^{x^{{}^{{{.\,}^{.\,^{.\,^{x}}}}}}}}_{k\text{ times}} \mod m,$$
where $x$ is repeated in power $k-1$ times and $m$ is any number.

That is, if $x=5$, $k=3$ and $m=3$, then I need to find $\ 5^{5^5} \mod 3$ .

Also note that $x$ is always a prime number.

It has been in my mind for quite a while now I can't find an answer.

Comment: Have you heard about Fermat's little theorem and Euler's theorem?

Comment: @RajivKaipa no that isn't the answer.

Comment: @Arthur yes i have , but how to solve using them?? any ideas??

Comment: I think you can just use modular arithmetic, so $x^{...^x}$ (k times) $\mod m$, will be the same as $x^r$ where $x^{...^x}$ (k-1 times) $\equiv r$ in the multiplicative group mod $m$. So in the particular example of $5^{5^5} \mod 3$ could be worked out by $5^5 \equiv 1 \mod 2 = 3-1$, so $5^{5^5} \equiv 5^1 \mod 3$, so is $2$.

Comment: @mdave16 thanks for the comment . 
 
can you explain a little more about what you did at each step?

Comment: Everything hinges on the fact that $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$. So if I do the more complicated example of $5\uparrow\uparrow 4 \mod 6$, we should see all the machinery required. Because $5^{\phi(6)} \equiv 1$, we should consider $5\uparrow\uparrow 3 \mod \phi(6) = 2$, but this is trivial since $5 \equiv 1 \mod 2$. So $5\uparrow\uparrow 4 \equiv 5^1 \mod 6$. So the remainder is 5. This is quite simple, but if you wouldn't mind waiting a week, I'll have more time then and can write a really nice answer.

Comment: If I forget, just ping me in the comments, also if my answer isn't that obvious yet. Once you know the answer, it's so obvious. I'm just considering the multiplicative group in Z/mZ and orders in such, but they are all quite similar.

Comment: Hmm, asked 2 days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249496/how-to-efficiently-find-a-prime-number-x-raised-to-the-power-x-k-times-mod/2249643#2249643, not exactly answered though

Answer (score 0):

$x \uparrow \uparrow k \mod m = x^{x \uparrow \uparrow (k-1) \mod \phi(m)} \mod m$.

Which is $O(k)$ repeating process.