# Compute modulo of prime power tower

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, power-towers

I have a prime number $p$, and I need to compute $p$ ↑↑ $k$ mod $m$.

here p ↑↑ k can be written as `p ^ (p ^ (p ^ (p ... k times)))`

for example -

$p = 5, k = 3, m = 3$

```
5 ↑↑ 3 = 5 ^ (5 ^ 5) % 3 = 2
```

Here $p$ is prime number, $2 <= p <= 10 ^ 8$, and $p - 2 <= m <= 10 ^ 8$.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  What kind of answer are you expecting here?

Comment: If $k$ is higher than a certain constant (different for every prime), the residue will be constant. That might be interesting to you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i need ans for   p ↑↑ k mod m

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367824/how-to-evalute-an-exponential-tower-modulo-a-prime

Comment: I'm fairly sure the solution hinges on Euler's theorem

Comment: But the thing which I find weird is that the same question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253065/use-fermats-little-theorem-to-find-remainder-of-powers#comment4633601_2253065) 4 hours ago and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249496/how-to-efficiently-find-a-prime-number-x-raised-to-the-power-x-k-times-mod/2249643#2249643)  2 days ago....

Comment: @RajivKaipa the world is very strange

Comment: I think this might be a homework question, and my guess would also lean to it being for a programming module since the questions use `%` rather than `\mod`. I have written a vague hint at a solution in the comments for the 4 hours ago one, and there is a better answer in the one 2 days ago.